# Typescript toString('hex') not working

Tags: typescript

Please someone help me convert a buffer to hex in typescript. I'm getting the error `error TS2554: Expected 0 arguments, but got 1.` when trying to call `data.toString('hex')`

```
const cipher = crypto.createCipher('aes192', config.secret);

let encrypted = '';
cipher.on('readable', () => {
    const data = cipher.read();
    if (data) {
        encrypted += data.toString('hex');
    }
});
cipher.on('end', () => {
    secret = encrypted;
    resolve(encrypted);
});

cipher.write('some clear text data');
cipher.end();
```

This code example is practically copy and pasted from [Node.js docs for crypto](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_class_cipher)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`cipher.read()` returns `string | Buffer` in which only the type `Buffer` has the overload for `toString` that accepts a parameter.

You can try asserting that `data` is of type `Buffer`:

```
encrypted += (data as Buffer).toString('hex');
```

Or you can use an `instanceof` [type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#instanceof-type-guards):

```
if (data instanceof Buffer)
    encrypted += data.toString('hex'); // `data` is inferred as `Buffer` here
```

Comment: This is a solid answer, thank you!! Just based on my coding style and preference, I went with the first option `(data as Buffer)` just because it seems to be asserting the behavior in the code as opposed to inferring a type.